# R - fitting a mixture distribution with fitdistrplus

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I have defined a mixture of a LogNormal and a Generalised Pareto (actuar) as follows:

```
dlnormgenpar<-function(x,
               w_lnorm,
               meanlog=0,
               sdlog=1,
               par_shape1=1,
               par_shape2=1,
               par_scale=1) {
  w_par=1-w_lnorm
  dln=dlnorm(x,meanlog = meanlog,sdlog = sdlog)
  dpar=dgenpareto(x,shape1=par_shape1,shape2=par_shape2,scale=par_scale)
  return(w_lnorm*dln+w_par*dpar)
}
```

I am trying to fit it to some data using fistdistrplus:

```
dist<-fitdist(data,"lnormgenpar")
```

However I receive the error:

```
Unknown starting values for distribution lnormgenpar.
```

If I expand the fitting function in the usual fitdistrplus way the error remains:

```
dist<-fitdist(data,"lnormgenpar",dparams=list(
  w_lnorm=0.5,
  meanlog=0,
  sdlog=1,
  par_shape1=1,
  par_shape2=1,
  par_scale=1
  ))
```

How should I pass my parameters in to the fitting function?

Thanks

Simon

Comment: From the help, dname, pname and qname should be defined. did you do that ?

Comment: Try adding `start=list(w_lnorm=0.1)` in the `fitdist` call